# Como fazer uma fade in no carregamento da página?

Tags: html, css, imagem

Estou tentando fazer um efeito de fade-in assim que a minha pagina é aberta utilizando apenas CSS, teria alguma forma de fazer isso? Os browser estão aptos a isso?

Fiz uma pesquisa e o que encontrei estou deixando aqui para ilustrar melhor a pergunta.

```
img {
             opacity: 0;

   -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;
           animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
       -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Você tentou utilizar o que você achou??

Comment: https://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/GorVRL

Comment: Se quer que isso aconteça no carregamento da página, terá que usar Javascript. Uma coisa é fazer uma animação random, em qualquer momento, outra é fazer quando a página estiver carregada. Detalhe isso na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um arquivo `.css` na pasta do seu projeto e adicione este código. Eu gosto de salvar como **efeitofade.css**

```
@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* Padrão */
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* Firefox */
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* Webkit */
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0.3; }
to { opacity: 1; } /* IE */
}​

@keyframes fadeout {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0.3; } /* Padrão */
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0.3; } /* Firefox */
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0.3; } /* Webkit */
}
@-ms-keyframes fadeout {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0.3; } /* IE */
}​
```

Feito isso adicione a chamada ao arquivo **efeitofade** na página onde você deseja aplicar este efeito.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="efeitofade.css">
```

Ótimo! Agora no css da página você adiciona esse estilo a tag `body`

```
body{
    animation: fadein 1s;
}
```

Nesse caso a animação irá durar 1s, se você quiser que dure um tempo diferente basta alterar na tag `body`

Comment: Ficou bom, obrigado!